# Trying to understand a recursive prolog procedure?

Tags: recursion, prolog

This was given as an example in a professor's lecture:

```
append([ ], A, A).
append([A|B], C, [A|D]) :- append(B,C,D).

Build a list:

?- append([a],[b],Y).
Y = [ a,b ]

Break a list into constituent parts:

?- append(X,[b],[a,b]).
X = [ a ]
?- append([a],Y,[a,b]).
Y = [ b ]
```

I've spent 3 hours trying to grasp it and can't. Hadn't had any trouble with any prolog concepts preceding this slide. There is no further explanation provided, no other information. This is all. If someone could walk me through how this procedure works, I would love them til death do us part.

Comment: Please consider the query `append(X, Y, [a,b])` too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to understand is the `:-` operator.

```
this_will_be_true :- if_this_is_true
```

Basically, whatever is on the right of `:-` is a precondition. A good example is:

```
sibling(X, Y) :- parent_child(Z, X), parent_child(Z, Y).
```

This basically means that X and Y are siblings if there exists a parent Z such that Z is the parent of both X and Y.

```
append([ ], A, A).
```

This line basically means that appending something to an empty list returns the something. It's the base case in the recursion.

```
append([A|B], C, [A|D]) :- append(B,C,D).
```

This line means that appending C to an existing list with A and B returns a list with A and D given that appending C to B returns D.

```
Build a list:

?- append([a],[b],Y).
Y = [ a,b ]
```

So, what's going on here is that Prolog returns the only possible value of `Y` that satisfies the two rules given the two initial values. Let's think about how this happens. This would need to first be evaluated by the second rule. So `[A|B]` is `[a]` and `C` is `[b]`.

So with `[A|B]` we have to go back to the first rule because `B` is empty list (it is `[ ]`). The first rule basically states that we can write `[a]` as `[a|[ ]]` and they are the same thing. So now we can go back to the second rule. `A` is `a`, `B` is `[ ]`, and `C` is `[b]`.

So now let's check the precondition of `append(B, C, D)`. This is `append([ ], [b], D)`. Once again, using the first rule, we can see that `D` is also `[b]`.

So `Y`, by the second rule definition, is `[A|D]`. Now that we know `D` is `[b]`, we know that `Y` is `[a, b]`.

I'll only do one of the breaking apart since they're basically the same thing.

```
?- append(X,[b],[a,b]).
X = [ a ]
```

So here, Prolog is going to return the only possible value of `X` so that the statement returns true. Let's take a look at the second rule. So we know that `[a, b]` is `[A|D]`. This means that `A` is `a` and `D` is `[b]`. We also know that `C` is `[b]`. So now, we need to look at the precondition to figure out what `B` is. `append(B, C, D)` translates to `append(B, [b], [b])`. Now, using the first rule, we know that `B` has to be `[ ]`. So now we know that `[A|B]` is `[a|[ ]]` which is the same as  `[a]`. Therefore, `X` must be `[a]`.

I hope this was a detailed enough explanation.

Comment: Welcome to SE! Really excellent answer. I think I just have a bit of a block with this. And I zoomed through learning imperative programming when I first started learning to program. No blocks anywhere. It was child's play to follow the instruction flow. But damn is this different.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my own understanding.

Your code describes the append operation of List.

At first here's an abbrevation that helps you to understand what is a list in prolog and what's the meaning of `|`:

```
[X1|[...[Xn|[]] = [X1,...Xn]
```

And append(A, B, C) means appending list B to A results in C.

Append A to empty list results in A:

```
append([ ], A, A).
```

If you want to append Y to X, say append(X, Y, _). Unless X is [], prolog would not know anything to do. You have to tell the rules to prolog by saying:

```
append([A|B], C, [A|D]) := append(B, C, D)
```

Then prolog will try to split X into form `[A|B]`. Then Y would be `A|D` where D is the list defined by C appended to B. `append(B, C, D)` is the way we tell prolog about this fact.

Comment: there's a problem in your sentence before the last. E.g. if `X = [1,2,3] = [A|B]` and `Y=[4,5]=C`, then `[A|[B|C]] = [1,[2,3],[4,5]]`.

Comment: No problem here. There's only one way to split X into [A|B], that is `[1,2,3]`(abbr of `[1|[2|[3|[]]]]`) to `[1|[2,3]]`. And `[A|[B|C]]` would be `[1|[[2,3,4,5]]]`([2,3,4,5] by append([2,3],[4,5],_)). Take care of when the abbrevation can apply.

Comment: `1 ?- X=[A|B], X=[1,2,3], C=[4,5], Z=[A|[B|C]].` produces: 

`X = [1, 2, 3] , 
A = 1 , 
B = [2, 3] , 
C = [4, 5] , 
Z = [1, [2, 3], 4, 5]`

Comment: I'm sorry. I figure out my bug now. `Y` is actually `A|D` where `D` is calculated by `append(B, C, _)`. Thanks for your comment.